# Is BigQuery GitHub contains all the data?

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery

[Documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github) that GitHub data collection contains all the code from a GitHub

> This 3TB+ dataset comprises the largest released source of GitHub activity to date. It contains a full snapshot of the content of more than 2.8 million open source GitHub repositories including more than 145 million unique commits, over 2 billion different file paths, and the contents of the latest revision for 163 million files, all of which are searchable with regular expressions.

But I can't find my code in it:

```
SELECT *
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] 
WHERE repo_name LIKE 'Everettss/%';
```

results with: `Query returned zero records.`

Here is example of one of my repo: https://github.com/Everettss/isomorphic-pwa

---

**EDIT**

After Felipe Hoffa answer, I've [added LICENCE](https://github.com/Everettss/isomorphic-pwa/commit/3f5c4067ff2f064ebfc9a0658f8839ad089c1af1) to my repo, so my example may not be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked sample project is not part of the BigQuery dataset, because the linked project is not open source.

What do I mean with this: For a project to be open source, at a minimum it needs to have a LICENSE file, and GitHub needs to be able to recognize that license as one of the already approved open source licenses.

Comment: I've added on Feb 5, 2018 MIT LICENSE file and `bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files` was updated on Mar 2, 2018. But still can not find my project in BigQuery. How is it possible?